# Software to make StackExchange usable without "accepting cookies" on every page every load?

Tags: web-browser

Since yesterday StackExchange has been giving me a pop-up to "accept all cookies".  If I do that, it disappears.  Until I go to the next page, or reload the current page, and it's back again.  (I'll admit that there are a few ubiquitous sites' scripts I don't trust, i.e. doubleclick and scorecardresearch, that I have not tried to enable (via NoScript) to "fix" the problem, because if that's the issue then I will need a general solution at my end anyway because they infest the whole web)

Is there a way (plugin or even a setting) to fix sites with this kind of problem by suppressing the broken/unwanted element (div class="ff-sans ps-fixed z-nav-fixed ws4 sm:w-auto p32 bg-black-750 fc-white bar-lg b16 l16 r16 js-consent-banner") from the browser end?

Comment: You have to accept some cookies or the site can't remember who you are from one page to the next. What you want to prevent are cross-site trackers, which is a totally different issue. What OS/browser? On Mac Safari with its built-in anti-tracking & a 3rd party ad-blocker I don't even see those two trackers listed [presumably because they're in the ads I'm not seeing]. They're not inherent to SE itself. All I see from SE are Google [also blocked by Safari, but I can examine what it blocked, I can't examine what the ad-blocker blocked] I've never been asked to

Comment: I did eventually figure out it was a site cookielaw.org that was to blame.  I  don't think it was this aggressive before.  I can enable its cookies then set the browser to discard all cookies whenever closed to solve the immediate problem.  *Nonetheless*, a browser-based tool to suppress unwanted elements by description would be very handy to have on hand for a wide range of future situations.

Answer (score 1):

[uBlock Origin](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock) is a general-purpose blocker. You can use it to block elements like the banner you have mentioned above. Some default filter lists include those banners as "annoyance" and block them as well. You can give it a try.